# Use PHP date() as SQL date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a SQL query that finds results from this day in history (ie today's date, not including the year)

I get the current date in PHP:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d", time());
```

I get no errors but also no results are returned when I use `$today` in this query:

```
SELECT name, date FROM births WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH($today) AND DAY(date) = DAY($today)
```

There are two rows in the date column that contain today's date in `Y-m-d` format. I'm not sure what's going on here. Is it because of an incompatible use of the variable? This is what my table structure looks like:

[image: births table structure]

Comment: What is your schema for that table? Is date an actual date or varchar? What is MONTH and DAY referring too? What's the error message returned when executing this query on the sql server itself?

Comment: Can you give the type of columns?

Comment: PHP doesn't work with people who can't think.

Answer (score 0):

dates in mysql should be surrounded in single quotes so this is what you are after

```
$today = date("Y-m-d", time());
$sql = "SELECT name, date FROM births WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(`{$today}`) AND DAY(date) = DAY('{$today}')";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```